# Getting Error when converting array to a variable in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have problem when converting multiple checkbox($request->courses) to a variable(checkbox1).Because I need to insert an array to Database.

```
public function store(Request $request) {

  $customer = new prospect;
  $customer->ProspectName = $request->ProspectName;
  $customer->NicNumber = $request->NicNumber;
  $customer->ContactNumber = $request->ContactNumber;
  $customer->ContactAddress = $request->ContactAddress;
  $customer->Comments = $request->Comments;
  $customer->ReferredThrough = $request->ReferredThrough;

  $checkbox1 = $request->courses; //courses is an array from form
  $chk = "";
  foreach ($checkbox1 as $chk1) {
    $chk .= $chk1 . ",";
  }
  $customer->IntrestedCourses = $chk;


  if ($customer->save()) {
    echo 'saved successfully';
  } else {
    echo 'error';
  }
}
```

But I'm getting error!

Comment: Can give the output of `$request->courses;`? and please state what error you got.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is working with the code you've provided?

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean?. I want to submit multiple checkbox values to a column in database.My checkbox name is courses.

Comment: Can you show the output of `dd($request->courses);`?

Comment: @RossWilson array:10 [▼
  0 => "FIT"
  1 => "BIT"
  2 => "BCS"
  3 => "PCM(SLIM)"
  4 => "MIT(SLIM)"
  5 => "MIS(SLIM)"
  6 => "CMA"
  7 => "AAT"
  8 => "Spoken English"
  9 => "General English"
]

Comment: Thanks. So, what isn't working with your code at the minute? You mentioned you're getting an error, what error are you getting?

Comment: $checkbox1 = $request->courses; //courses is an array from form
  $chk = "";
  foreach ($checkbox1 as $chk1) {
    $chk .= $chk1 . ",";
  }
  $customer->IntrestedCourses = $chk;                                                        when I add  this part. I'm getting error that "Array to string conversion";

Comment: @RossWilson  $checkbox1 = $request->courses; Is this correct?

Comment: If `$request->courses` really returned an array, then you could do something like this: `$chk = implode(',', $request->courses)` without foreach loop